# Angular return filtered array for use with ngFor based on items values

Tags: angular

Hi using angular 6 I need to render OPTION for a SELECT based on properties of the JSON returned via the service.

I am using ngFor for basic rendering such as:

```
<select>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let project of data">
        <ng-container *ngIf="(project.projectItems.length !=0)" >
            <option>{{project.projectName}}</option>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</select>
```

This provides a populated SELECT interface for Projects that contain Items, however it is not yet acting on the values of the data.

Basically I need help filtering the data to generate the interface based on a few scenarios:

1. Only render an OPTION if a project contains items
2. Only render an option if a project is active
3. Only render an option if a project has at least 1 item set to active

Returning JSON is shown below so I would expect to see a SELECT with only 2 items (Project 1 and Project 3):

```
data = [
    {
        "projectName" : "Project 1",
        "Active" : true,
        "projectItems" : [
            {
                "itemName" : "Item 1",
                "Active" : true
            },
            {
                "itemName" : "Item 2",
                "Active" : false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "projectName" : "Project 2",
        "Active" : true,
        "projectItems" : [
            {
                "itemName" : "Item 1",
                "Active" : false
            },
            {
                "itemName" : "Item 2",
                "Active" : false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "projectName" : "Project 3",
        "Active" : true,
        "projectItems" : [
            {
                "itemName" : "Item 1",
                "Active" : true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "projectName" : "Project 4",
        "Active" : false,
        "projectItems" : [
            {
                "itemName" : "Item 1",
                "Active" : true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "projectName" : "Project 5",
        "Active" : true,
        "projectItems" : []
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pre-filter the array in your angular component so you don't have to include this logic in the template. Here is some filtering code that matches your 3 requirements:

1. project contains items
2. project is active
3. project has at least 1 item set to active

Here is the filtering, you can execute it in the snippet below:

```
dataFiltered = this.data.reduce((accum, item) => {
    if (item.projectItems && item.Active && item.projectItems.some(p => p.Active)) {
      accum.push(item);
    }
    return accum;
  }, []);
```

```js
data = [
  {
      "projectName" : "Project 1",
      "Active" : true,
      "projectItems" : [
          {
              "itemName" : "Item 1",
              "Active" : true
          },
          {
              "itemName" : "Item 2",
              "Active" : false
          }
      ]
  },
  {
      "projectName" : "Project 2",
      "Active" : true,
      "projectItems" : [
          {
              "itemName" : "Item 1",
              "Active" : false
          },
          {
              "itemName" : "Item 2",
              "Active" : false
          }
      ]
  },
  {
      "projectName" : "Project 3",
      "Active" : true,
      "projectItems" : [
          {
              "itemName" : "Item 1",
              "Active" : true
          }
      ]
  },
  {
      "projectName" : "Project 4",
      "Active" : false,
      "projectItems" : [
          {
              "itemName" : "Item 1",
              "Active" : true
          }
      ]
  },
  {
      "projectName" : "Project 5",
      "Active" : true,
      "projectItems" : []
  }
];

dataFiltered = this.data.reduce((accum, item) => {
  if (item.projectItems && item.Active && item.projectItems.some(p => p.Active)) {
      accum.push(item);
    }
    return accum;
  }, []);
  
console.log(dataFiltered);
```

The `*ngIf` is no longer necessary with this data. The `*ngFor` can also be placed on the `<option>` directly.

```
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let project of dataFiltered">{{ project.projectName }}</option>
</select>
```

If your data comes from an API, do the filtering when you receive this data.

If you only need the projectNames from the filtered data, you could also change its shape to an array of names:

```
names = this.data.reduce((accum, item) => {
    if (item.projectItems && item.Active && item.projectItems.some(p => p.Active)) {
      accum.push(item.projectName);
    }
    return accum;
  }, []);
```

And use this for the options:

```
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let name of names">{{ name }}</option>
</select>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thats great and thank you for the additional improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select>
<ng-container *ngFor="let project of data">
    <ng-container *ngIf="(project.projectItems!.length !=0)" >
        <option>{{project!.projectName}}</option>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

I am assuming your accessing the data via a service so it may be undefined if the stream is asynchronous.